# How to define a Command for a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm wondering if is possible bound a `Command` to the `ComboBox`, I've actually implemented the `Command` logic on a `Menu`, in this way:

```
 <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <MenuItem Header="Theme" Width="100" 
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ThemeColorMenuItemStyle}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Themes, Mode=OneTime}" />
</Menu>
```

where the `ItemContainerStyle` have this structure:

```
<Style x:Key="AccentColorMenuItemStyle"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroMenuItem}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding }" />
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.ApplyAccentCommand, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource AccentMenuIcon}" />
    </Style>
```

and this is the command:

```
 public ICommand ApplyAccentCommand { get; } = new SimpleCommand(o => ApplyAccent((Swatch)o));

    private static void ApplyAccent(Swatch swatch)
    {
        new PaletteHelper().ReplaceAccentColor(swatch);
    }
```

this `MenuItem` bound a `Theme` collection provided by `MaterialDesignInXaml` as `Swatch` model, that have this class:

```
public class Swatch
{
    public Swatch(string name, IEnumerable<Hue> primaryHues, IEnumerable<Hue> accentHues);

    public string Name { get; }
    public Hue ExemplarHue { get; }
    public Hue AccentExemplarHue { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Hue> PrimaryHues { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Hue> AccentHues { get; }
    public bool IsAccented { get; }

    public override string ToString();
}
```

so, returning to the question: is possible have this logic on a `ComboBox`? 'cause the `MenuItem` doesn't have the `SelectedItem` property, and I need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Blend Behaviors and bind an event to a command. You will need to refer `System.Windows.Interactivity` namespace, which you can get by installing the `Expression.Blend.Sdk` NuGet package.

Once installed, add the following XAML namespace to your page:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

And then use it as follows:

```
<ComboBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

The `MvvmLight` toolkit also offers more advanced version of `InvokeCommandAction` called `EventToCommand` that allows you to specify a `EventArgsConverter` as well to be able to get a specific value from the event's `EventArgs` instance.

Comment: hope that the SelectedItem will be added in future

Comment: `SelectedItem` is there, but you have to bind it to a property. There you can trigger the `Command` from the setter of the property however :-) .